# Is it possible to view Android hidden files/folders on Windows 10?

Tags: android, windows, hidden-files

I have several hidden folders (prefixed with a dot '.') on my Android device and I would like to view them on my PC (Windows 10) when I plug it in via USB - is this possible?

Comment: Why would Windows care about the \*nix convention that file names starting with a period should be considered *hidden*?

Comment: I don't know, this is why I am asking

Comment: On the famous #winprog IRC channel there was the old saying: "If it takes like 2 minutes to try, why not simply try it?"

Comment: Try what? Try navigate to the folder by typing in a period before the folder name?

Comment: Did you ever find the solution?

Comment: @Zeeshanef Gosh this was 5 years ago, I can't remember :D Sorry.